# What is the correct use of idioms in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Choose the correct answer, Jeff made _ his neglect by taking Jane out for dinner next day.

> a) in for
>   b) up for
>   c) up against
>   d) in against

Answer (score 2):

Up for is the correct answer.

> Jeff made up for his neglect by taking Jane out for dinner next day.

**Make up for** is an idiom that is used to mean "to compensate for someone or something someone did." For example:

> We all had to do extra work to **make up for** Harry, who was very
>   tired from being out late the night before. We will certainly make up
>   for what we failed to do.

Made is the past form of make hence, made up for is the correct answer.

Comment: I edited it....